# BSc and further career in Academia on different subject

Tags: mathematics, career-path, stem, academic-freedom

Currently pursuing a Bachelor if Finance, but I have a huge interest on Statistics. I was wondering whether BSc in a non technical subject (With technical I mean Statistics, Mathematics, Computer Science etc.) affects a potential academic career in Statistics.

Can MSc and PhD in Statistics or Applied Mathematics enable an academic career in these fields?

Answer (score 2):

You might check in advance the application requirements for the MSc and/or PhD in Statistics or Applied Mathematics. By doing so, you will have a better overview on the technical competences you have to show to receive admission to the program.

In addition, you can show your interest by taking part or leading extracurricular activities with strong technical components (e.g., programming clubs, [competitive programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Competitive_programming#Notable_competitions), and so on.). Admission boards not only take into account your degree but the sum of your experience and potential.

Comment: Actually I am not referring to getting accepted on a MSc or PhD In Statistics or Applied Mathematics but being hired as an Assistant Professor or Lecturer teaching these topics

Answer (score 2):

To first approximation, once you have a PhD and a sufficient research track record,  your previous degrees don’t matter.  (In fact, if you have a strong research record in field X, gaving a PhD in field Y doesn’t matter.)  If anything, having a more diverse academic backgound will make you a *more* attractive faculty candidate (all else being equal).

To give some anecdotal evidence: One of my academic siblings has a bachelor’s degree in classical civilization and a PhD in computer science.  She is now a tenured full professor and former department chair in computer science.

Comment: That was the answer wanted to hear.